# c++ shell extension - can't register on 32-Bit

Tags: c++, explorer, windows-shell, regsvr32, shell-extensions

I've created a C++ Shell Context Menu Extension using [this Template](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CppShellExtContextMenuHandl-410a709a/sourcecode?fileId=21956&pathId=1773984930).

On 64-Bit computers, it works great, but I can't register it on 32-Bit computers. Even the unmodified original version of the project does not work.

I know that I have to set the target to Win32, and then compile it.

Does somebody know why I can't register it?

The error message is:

> The module "fmshell32.dll" failed to load.    Make sure the binary is
>   stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with
>   the binary or dependent .DLL files.    The specified module could not
>   be found.

I tried to register it using

```
regsvr32 extension.dll
```

I tried it on a 32-bit computer and I used the 32-bit dll.

Comment: Is runtime statically linked?

Comment: The error message you posted came from `regsvr32 extension.dll`?

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: yes, this message is displayed after executing the command.

Comment: @alexm: I used the default settings of the project.

Comment: Try check dependencies with depends.exe - it helped me on several occasions.

Comment: @alexm: I´ve already done this, but it´s really hard to find anything with it. There are over 6 DLLs missing (on a Win7 and on a XP machine, both brandnew setup), so I don´t know how helpful it is. I´ve already downloaded the DLLs, but it didn´t work...

Comment: Are you sure you are not shipping the *debug* version of the dll, and it works on the 64 bit computer because you have VS installed there? Have you installed the correct C++ runtime/tried to switch to the statically-linked CRT?

Comment: @Matteo Italia: I use the release dll. It works on other x64, too. What runtime has to be installed? Isn´t it installed by default? I´m usein VS2010, how can I switch to static linked CRT? Have you tried to register it by your own? would be interesting if its just me with this error...

Comment: project config allows you to choose static runtime linking

Comment: @David Heffernan: But which property is it? I could only find "Configuration Type","Use of ATL" and "Use of MFC". They allow me to set it so something with "static", but I don´t think you meant that..

Comment: Configutation Properties | C/C++ | Code Generation | Runtime Library. You want /MT.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thanks! I tried it with the original version. But there is now a new error: The module "CppShellExtContextMenuHandler.dll" was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80070005.

For more information about this problem, search online using the error code as a search term.

Comment: I bet that you are not running with elevated privileges. Make sure you run regsvr32 from a command prompt that you started with "Run as Administrator".

Comment: THANKS DAVID! YOU ARE AWESOME! ^^ it works! Add it as anwer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: @David Heffernan: I noticed, that it sill does not work on XP 32-Bit SP3. "Procedure not found" Do you have another idea to solve this?